# RC + DIode Problem

Tags: circuit-analysis, capacitor, resistors, diodes

[image][image]Consider every component to be ideal.
V_in is a square pulse with dc level 0 and amplitude = 10 (Basically square pulse at +-5V)
Find v_out vs time (draw the waveform)

Solution :  im not sure whether the 2nd waveform is correct or not. can anyone confirm?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a homework problem with no effort shown.

Comment: sorry im new here. So somehow my solution page didnt get added properly.

Comment: Try again.  Since you have a series capacitor your first pulse will produce more of a differentiated signal on Vout. Later pulses will create a negative signal mainly below ground due to the diode direction.

Comment: @Nedd can you explain a bit more? I didnt get it.

Comment: @CodeXxxx - Read up on differentiator circuits. The rest of the signal going negative is just the result of the diode orientation. You can even download a circuit simulator and verify the operation for yourself.